# How should I use relations on views instead tables?

Tags: yii, view, foreign-keys, relation

I'm new to Yii, so I have a lot to learn.

I am about to understand relations in models, and I try to use a `BELONGS_TO` relation.
But it doesn't work, because I would like to point my FK to a view and not to a table.
Any idea to make relations between tables and views?

Comment: would you please explain how can you relate a FKey to view? Relation is a concept for Models and models deal with DB tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use database views just as you can use tables with Gii and Yii. And just like with tables, you need an Active Record model for every database view.

Just give the name of your database view to Gii and it will generate a model for your view, along with the existing relations.

Check this thread on the Yii forums for more information: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/1979-yii-dont-support-model-based-on-database-view/